# Multiple objects using same onClickListener; how to limit number of touch events?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm using a TableLayout.
I add in x number of TableRows; this table ends up with equal number of rows and columns.

I add in ImageViews and call .setOnClickListener(onClickListener), where onClickListener is of type View.OnClickListener

How do I limit that onClickListener object to only process one click at a time? That way, only one ImageView can be selected at a time; otherwise, this game is too easy for the user, and I am a sadist that needs to see people struggle a bit more to win.

I've tried playing around with android:beforeDescendants on the tableLayout and having an OnClickListener or OnTOuchListener there, but it gets messy fast, and I am assuming there is a better/easier way I'm overlooking.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1.) define a class variable

```
boolean processingTouch = false;
```

2.) when the on touch event is fired, inside the function put:

```
if(processingTouch == false){
    processingTouch = true;
    //do stuff here
    processingTouch = false;
}
```

This way while the button is touched, other buttons won't do anything in there on click listener until the touched button has finished executing it's events.

I haven't tested this yet.